# show a field if only a certain radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

i have two radio buttons used in my form and follow to those two radio buttons i have another field.
I want to show that field if only a certain radio button is checked.otherwise by default it should be hidden.

- My code

  **Payment Type**

  ```
          <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-radio">
          <input type="radio" name="group">
          <div class="item-content">
          Immediate Payment
          </div>
          <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
          </label>
          <label class="item item-radio">
          <input type="radio" name="group">
          <div class="item-content">
          Scheduled Payment
          </div>
          <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
          </label>
          </div>

          <label><h4><b>Effective Date*</b></h4></label>
          <input type="date" >
  ```

Here i want to show effective date field only if the user checks the Scheduled Payment radio button.  How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("input[name=group]").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'scheduled' && $(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#effectiveWrapper").show();
    } else {
        $("#effectiveWrapper").hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wdckktz7/

AngularJS Code

```
<div ng-show="payment == 'scheduled'">
    <label>
         <h4><b>Effective Date*</b></h4>

    </label>
    <input type="date" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/orr1p1eg/

Comment: how to do this in angularjs?

Comment: plx check my answer again

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input:radio[name='group']").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value == 'Scheduled Payment'){
        $("#div").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#div").hide();
    }

});
```

and put your date input inside the div:

```
<div id="div">
    <label><h4><b>Effective Date*</b></h4></label>
    <input type="date" >
</div>
```

Comment: how to do this in angularjs?